# Referencing Names Cells in IF statments VBA

Tags: excel, formula

SO I have a bunch of named cells in Excel (latest version) and I'm trying to use the following formula to reference them without copying zeroes :

=IF(named_cell,named_cell,"")

but I get #VALUE! However if I use

=named_cell

it works fine.  Why isn't it working in the IF formula ????

Answer (score 1):

It depends exactly what you want to test for:

```
=IF(OR(LEN(named)=0,named=0),"",named)
```

Tests for a single named cell containing zero or empty (but not a space character).

Comment: I just want to test that the named cell .....  ah I can use ISNOTNULL...

Answer (score 0):

Use the names properly *(make sure `named_cell` contains a Boolean)*:
Cell **A1** has the Name *"ayeone"* and the value True
Cell **B1** has the Name *"beeone"* and the value *Bee*
Cell **C1** has the formula:  `=IF(ayeone,beeone,"")`:

[image]

In *VBA*:

```
Sub WhatsInAName()
    MsgBox Range("ayeone").Address & vbCrLf & Range("ayeone").Value
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the named cells contain either text or are blank (no true numbers), zeroes returned from blank cells can be avoided by appending a zero-length string to the result.

```
=named_cell&""
```

This method can also be applied to VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH that would return zeroes from blank cells.